# How to define a c macro with multiple statement

Tags: c, linux, unix, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to define a macro that has two line/statements, it's like:

```
#define FLUSH_PRINTF(x) printf(x);fflush(stdout);
```

but it can't work due to the limit that C macros cannot work with ';'.

Is there any reasonable way to work around it?

P.S.:  **I know the upper example is weird and I should use something like a normal function.**  but it's just a simple example that I want to question about **how to define a multiple statement Macro**.

Comment: `but it can't works due to the limit that C Macro can not work with ';'.` What do you mean? Why not write a function?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you do want to do that: `#define FLUSH_PRINTF(x) {printf(x); fflush(stdout);}`

Comment: Shouldn't fflush be avoided?

Comment: @KamiKaze: `fflush` is fine for output streams - it's UB for input streams in general (although supported on some platforms).

Comment: @tkausl I know the upper example is weird and I should use something like a normal function. but it's just a simple example that I want to question about how to define a multiple statement Macro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an appropriate time to use the [`do { ... } while (0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros?rq=1) idiom.
This is also an appropriate time to use [variadic macro arguments](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).

```
#define FLUSH_PRINTF(...) \
    do { \
        printf(__VA_ARGS__); \
        fflush(stdout); \
    } while (0)
```

You could also do this with a wrapper function, but it would be more typing, because of the extra boilerplate involved with using `vprintf`.

```
 #include <stdarg.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 /* optional: */ static inline 
 void
 flush_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
 {
     va_list ap;
     va_start(ap, fmt);
     vprintf(fmt, ap);
     va_end(ap);
     fflush(stdout);
 }
```

Comment: Why an inline function? A normal function would  work just as well.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  I know the upper example is weird and I should use something like a normal function. but it's just a simple example that I want to question about how to define a multiple statement Macro.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I suppose it doesn't need to be inline, no.

Answer (score 3):

Use the multiple expression in macro

#define FLUSH_PRINTF(x) (printf(x), fflush(stdout))